# Get child of ScrollView programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview

I have made a custom `ScrollView` which has a single child inside it (a layout). Finding the child by ID using `findViewByid` in the `CustomScrollView.java` causes the app to crash, so is it possible to find it in a simple manner similar to `this` (which detects the custom scrollview) or `getParent()` (which detects the parent layout that both the scrollview and the child is inside of)?

I'm trying to apply `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);` to the child of the custom `ScrollView`.

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.example.test4.CustomScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/dynamic_status_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/dynamic_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</com.example.test4.CustomScrollView>
```

Code inside `CustomScrollView.java` where I want to add `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent`:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Add here
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
```

**Problem:**

In short, I want to find the child of the custom ScrollView, the layout with the id `dynamic_status`, without using `findViewById`.

Comment: Its java not kotlin in java you need to use findviewbyid

Comment: @Ashish Oh ok, sorry, I'm not familiar with kotlin and quite new to java. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    ((ConstraintLayout)getChildAt(0)).requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

You can always access child Views (Views nested deeper than your current View) with `getChildAt`. Since `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent` is only available to ViewGroups you have to cast it either directly to your ConstraintLayout or - for better reuseability - to a ViewGroup.

Please note that I had not included any checks if the child is available.

This code is also the same for Kotlin and Java. It does not make any difference (syntactically yes, but the concept is the same).

Comment: Thank you, the code correctly identifies the child `((ConstraintLayout)getChildAt(0))`. Oh okay, thanks for the explanation for `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent`. Truth is though, I have yet to make it work and haven't noticed any difference when adding it to `onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {}` or `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent p_event) {}`. I suppose it's a bit off-topic, but I have problems enabling click events for the child inside the custom ScrollView as well as scrolling for the scrollview simultaneously.

Comment: You're welcome! Can you explain your problem a bit further? I don't quite understand what you want to accomplish yet. Do you want to trigger onClick of a child whilst scrolling the ScrollView?

Comment: Hm yes, that could be fine, as long as click (or touch) events for the views in the child works without disabling the scroll function of the scrollview. So far it has been working either only for the child's views or the scrollview. I have experimented with the MotionEvents DOWN, MOVE, and UP, true/false boolean ex. `if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {disable_scroll = false;}`, but the problem is that both a click and swipe require `ACTION_DOWN`.

Comment: I understand your problem but I can't really think of a convenient way to solve this. However, maybe an [Article](http://codetheory.in/understanding-android-input-touch-events/) about touch events will help you.

Comment: Okay, it's alright, I'm already grateful for the help you've provided. I'll read the article, thank you.